# Find MAX value From each decimal value

Tags: mysql

I need to find only those record whose value is Maximum in sequence id.

for ex.

```
seq_id 
===============
239334.001
239341.001
239344.001
239345.001
239447.001
239334.004
239341.004
239344.004
239345.004
239447.004
239334.007
239341.007
239344.007
239345.007
239447.007
```

Now I need to  find only those seq_id whose decimal value is maximum.
for ex.

```
seq_id 
===============

239334.007
239341.007
239344.007
239345.007
239447.007
```

So any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean Greater Than?

Comment: Or do you mean where `.007` is present in the `seq_id`

Comment: @RiggsFolly No Maximum.

Comment: Well if you want the MAXIMUM there will only be ONE answer not 5

Comment: But i need all max value with decimal like whose contain .007.

Comment: Ah I think I get it, they are 2 seperate pieces of data that you have stored in one column right?

Comment: actally, its increment when ever its edited. so i need max for each sequence.

Comment: Is it to late to throw it away and do it properly

Comment: Its properly need the solution.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something based on this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TT1 WHERE MYVAL-FLOOR(MYVAL)=
(select MAX(MYVAL-FLOOR(MYVAL)) DECIM_MAX
      FROM TT1
     ) ;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE TT1 (MYVAL NUMERIC(10,3));
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES (239334.001);
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES (239345.007);
INSERT INTO TT1 VALUES (239447.007);


SELECT * 
FROM TT1 WHERE MYVAL-FLOOR(MYVAL)=
(select MAX(MYVAL-FLOOR(MYVAL)) DECIM_MAX
      FROM TT1
     ) 
       ;
```

Output:

```
    MYVAL
1   239345,007
2   239447,007
```